# Updating Hyperledger Composer Contract after it is saved

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am beginner to Hyperledger Composer and I would like to ask is it possible to update the properties inside contract after it is linked with an asset?

I was able to update properties in asset but when I tried, for example:

```
document.contract.totalSigners = 3;

return getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Document')
  .then(function (documentRegistry) {
    return documentRegistry.update(document);
  });
```

Result: the properties inside Contract was not updated.

I know Contract is linked to Asset so I would like to know is it allowed to update contract or is it other ways to perform the updating process?

Also, as I have Owner asset linked to Contract, how can I remove the owner if he deletes the document in future? Below is my architecture:

```
participant Owner extends Business { 
}

asset Contract identified by contractId {
  o String contractId
  --> Owner owner
}

asset Document identified by documentId {
  o String documentId
  o DocumentStatus status
  --> Contract contract
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to update an Asset.  The trade-network sample does exactly that - changing the owner of an existing Asset.

```
/**
* Track the trade of a commodity from one trader to another 
* @param {org.acme.trading.Trade} trade - the trade to be processed
* @transaction
*/
async function tradeCommodity(trade) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

// set the new owner of the commodity
trade.commodity.owner = trade.newOwner;
const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.acme.trading.Commodity');

// persist the state of the commodity
await assetRegistry.update(trade.commodity);
}
```

(The trade network sample can be found in Playground or via [github](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/tree/master/packages/trade-network) ) 
Note that this sample uses async / await instead of promises, and this works with later versions of Composer.  Hopefully you are using Composer v0.19 and Fabric 1.1 - if not, upgrade if possible.

The Owner can be deleted in a Transaction and you would access the participantRegistry.remove instead of the assetRegistry - you might want to check that owner doesn't own other contracts before deleting though, and you could use a Query for that.

Comment: It's really helpful, I got the whole picture already. Thanks for your answer.